# Minimal BASH-like line editing at startup

Tags: boot, luna

Minimal BASH-like line editing at startup. I used a live key of elementary Luna to install and execute boot-repair and got the following result:

http://paste2.org/wVCzAxOC

Despite the operation I still have the Minimal BASH-like line editing at startup.

Any idea?

Answer (score 6):

I managed to fix this problem by checking the *Purge GRUB before reinstalling it* in the *GRUB option* tab.